# Why is my RecycleView not working as expected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am having an exam and this code won't work for me.

My RecycleView won't work and I don't know how to save the deposit amount and minus the withdrow from the amount that already giving. This is the mainAcitvity file and RvAdapter file:

MainActivity.kt

```
       package com.example.anhar

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var clRoot: ConstraintLayout
    private lateinit var bignum: TextView
    private lateinit var cash: ArrayList<String>
    private lateinit var rvMoney: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var diposte: EditText
    private lateinit var dipbtn: Button
    private lateinit var withdrow: EditText
    private lateinit var withbtn: Button


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        clRoot = findViewById(R.id.clRoot)
        cash = ArrayList()
        rvMoney = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvMoney)
        bignum = findViewById(R.id.amount)


      rvMoney.adapter = RvAdapter(this)
     rvMoney.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        diposte = findViewById(R.id.dip)
        dipbtn = findViewById(R.id.dipbtn)


        withdrow = findViewById(R.id.with)
        withbtn = findViewById(R.id.withbtn)

        diposte.setOnClickListener { adddipMessage() }
        withdrow.setOnClickListener { addwidMessage() }

        private fun addwidMessage() {
            val w = withdrow.text
            if (w.isNotEmpty())
                bignum.text = " - ${withdrow.text}"
            withdrow.text.clear()
            withdrow.clearFocus()
        }

        private fun adddipMessage() {
            val d = diposte.text
            if (d.isNotEmpty())
                bignum.text = " + ${diposte.text}"
            diposte.text.clear()
            diposte.clearFocus()

        }
    }
```

This is for the RecycleView and I don't know why it is not working.

RvAdapter.kt

```
     package com.example.anhar

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.rvmain.view.*


class RvAdapter(private val money: ArrayList<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RvAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {
    class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        return ItemViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.rvmain,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val moneys = money[position]

        holder.itemView.apply {
            rvMoney.text = moneys
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = money.size
}
```

Comment: Where are you passing the list into the RvAdapter?

Comment: your adapter's list is always empty, isn't it ?

Comment: How is this working `RvAdapter(this)` ? You adapter receives an array but the argument is activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
rvMoney.adapter = RvAdapter(this) // wrong way to pass list
```

You must pass your list here.
Change constructor invocation like that

```
rvMoney.adapter = RvAdapter(listOf("Money1", "Money2"))
```

Comment: you say `wrong way to pass list` but will using `RvAdapter(this)` even compile

Comment: Compile-time error occurs when you pass 'this' to constructor of RvAdapter. Because 'this' refers to the closest scope, which is AppCompatActivity in your code, and AppCompatActivity is not subclass of ArrayList<String>.

Comment: yeah, I guess OP never really said what was wrong, i thought they said the recycler stays empty which wouldn't make sense